# Random SuspiciousOperation Exception on Django project

Tags: python, django, deployment, production

I have a project running for about six months now, and a week ago it started to raise random SuspiciousOperation exceptions, the curios things is that all of them happened during nighttime. oO

The page works fine if I try to browse it and I can not duplicate the error.

This is the report that Django automatically sends me:

This is the report that Django automatically sends me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 57, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 72, in get_host
    "Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): %s" % host)

SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): onlyfonts.net.


<WSGIRequest
path:/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': '',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip',
 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP': '2400:8900::f03c:91ff:feae:eff7',
 'HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY': 'XX',
 'HTTP_CF_RAY': '10e5f8a0424d018d-NRT',
 'HTTP_CF_VISITOR': '{"scheme":"http"}',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'onlyfonts.net.',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'curl/7.26.0',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '2400:8900::f03c:91ff:feae:eff7, 108.162.226.18',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'RAW_URI': '/',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '108.162.226.18',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '80',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'onlyfonts.net.',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/0.12.2',
 'gunicorn.socket': <socket._socketobject object at 0x94ba764>,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0xb72fc0d0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper at 0x8af826c>,
 'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x94b61ec>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

And yes, my domain is added to ALLOWED_HOSTS, as I mentioned, the page works fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your host "onlyfonts.net"?

Comment: Do you have a - in host?

Comment: Yes, that is my host. The most curios thing is that this starting to happen without applying any changes to the server setup.